# Laravel Dropdown Selected item send to edit view

Tags: laravel, view, dropdown

This is my **view** index page

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('cname','Clients: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('cname',[''=>'Select Category']+$client,null,['class'=>'form-control selectpicker']) !!}
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Edit</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
public function index() {
    $client = Client::pluck('cname','clientid')->all();
    return view('client.index', compact('client'));
}
```

How can i get select item from dropdown and from button click send the selected details to edit view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
// Controller

public function index()
{
    $roles = Roles::all();
    $selectedRole = User::first()->role_id;

    return view('my_view', compact('roles', 'selectedRole');
}
```

And then in your view

```
<select class="form-control m-bot15" name="role_id">

    @if ($roles->count())

        @foreach($roles as $role)
            <option value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ $selectedRole == $role->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $role->name }}</option>    

    @endif

</select>
```